# django ошибка при добавлении файла на русском языке

Tags: django

Сделал возможность добавлять документы на сайт, на локальном сервере все работает. На хостинге же при попытке добавить документ с русским названием выдает ошибку:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/blog/file/add/
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 54-58: ordinal not in range(128)

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: iles/Устав_СНТ_
```

Если добавлять этот же файл, но переименованным на английский язык, все работает как надо. Я не понимаю в чем ошибка.

### models.py

```
class File(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название файла')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Время добавления')
    document = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='files/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Документ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Документы'
        ordering = ['-created_date']
```

Answer (score 0):

Чем вызвана ошибка я не знаю, но ее можно обойти если автоматически переименовывать получаемые файлы

```
    class File(models.Model):
        def get_upload_file_name(self, file_name):
            return 'files/{}'.format(slugify(file_name))
        
            title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название файла')
            created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Время добавления')
            document = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
```